# "England in sight of victory" vs. "Victory in sight for England"

Tags: grammaticality

> England in sight of victory

This was the headline in a leading newspaper but I can't help but feel that there is something wrong in it. I would have phrased it as:

> Victory in sight for England

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 4):

They are both correct and slightly idiomatic. One phrase uses *for* while the other uses *of*.

Perhaps you might find it easier to accept:

> England **within** sight of victory

The ODO has [this to say](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sight):

> **in (or within) sight of**
>   so as to see or be seen from:
>   *I climbed the hill and came **in sight of the house***
>   within reach of; close to attaining:
>   *he was safe for the moment and **in sight of victory***

Answer (score 0):

Both could be used and I wouldn't want to say "wrong!" but I would say that *Victory in sight for England* were preferable.

This is because you have consider the Agent role. While 'England' - which points to team of humans rather than the country - are capable of seeing victory, or  having victory in sight, 'victory' - which is a concept - is not capable of having England in sight, so to my ears it sounds a little odd.

Comment: Precisely. I wanted to make sure if personifying victory was grammatically correct or not. Seems like it is.

Comment: I don't understand why you think [in sight of victory](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in+sight+of+victory%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is "odd". It seems perfectly normal to me (and to over 2000 writers there in Google Books).

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the construction. In both examples, *England* is the agent, just as both *I am in sight of the pub* and *The pub is in sight* mean I can see it, not vice versa.

Comment: Personification is not essentially a grammatical concept but a stretching of meaning, treating non-persons (including inanimate objects or concepts) as if they were human. All of the following are grammatically acceptable: _'What an idiot!' thought Hermione / the dog / the radiator,_ but only the first two would normally be considered acceptable. Doubtless _victory_ has been personified, but this is not the case in your example.

Comment: And in your example, it is 'England' (a synecdoche for the England team), not 'victory', being referenced by 'sight'. X is within sight of Y means that X can see Y _or_ Y can see X (or both) (and provided they're looking in the right direction!) when used literally. _The Greek soldiers were now in sight of the guards on the wall._ If only one has eyes, that restricts the literal meaning, of course: _I came in sight of the house._ Here, only the England players have eyes, and the idiom kicks in according to that restriction: _England (are) close to attaining victory._ Cf England eye up victory.

Comment: @TimLymington~ I didn't say agent. I said Agent. They are not always the same thing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth~ I am not referring to personification, but to thematic roles.

Comment: @?:I was addressing (or thought I was) pareshnakhe re his 'I wanted to make sure if personifying victory was grammatically correct or not. Seems like it is.'.